# Retrieve a BLOB image from database and display it as Image on javafx

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, phpmyadmin

I have an Image in a database as a Blob and I want to display it as an Image on javafx, I did this:

```
Image imagenMonstruo = null;
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(12);
InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
System.out.println(is.toString());
imagenMonstruo = new Image(is);
is.close();
```

And added to the object but when I run the application i don't get any error but I still don't getting the image display, with the system.out.println I get:

```
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@e0debc3
```

So I don't know if i'm doing this properly and the others similar question asked here doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

EDIT where i get the image from my pc and it works but my problem is the image from the database in Blob format.

```
File file = new File("C:\\\\xampp\\htdocs\\monsterHunter\\imagenes\\anjanath.jpg");
BufferedImage imagen = ImageIO.read(file);
Image imagenMonstruo = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imagen, null );
```

Comment: Do you actually add the `Image` to a `ImageView`, draw it in a `Canvas` or in a `BackgroundFill`?

Comment: yes I do, i can add an image from my pc, look at my edit please, but i can do that because is an image in jpg and not a Blob file like i have to do because the image is stored in the database

Comment: Does writing the data contained in the blob to a `.jpg` file result in the correct image? (BTW: `Image`s can be loaded from a file without the need to create a `BufferedImage`: `Image imagenMonstruo = new Image(file.toURI().toString());`)

Comment: Fabian thank you for answering, indeed the file uploaded was wrong and i tried to add a image to my database directly and then the image is shown in the program so thank you so much, my problem is that i sent an Image to the database instead a Blob and because that i cannot read it, so that's it the code works, but how I convert an Image to a Blob file?